# Rotate text on half of custom circular axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a visual where I'm constructing a circular linear scale on the outskirts of a donut/pie chart. Currently, the labels are easy enough to read on the right-hand side, but on the left-hand side the text is pretty much upside down and thus hurting readability. Here is the [block](https://bl.ocks.org/AbnormalDistribution-2020/d4eabff2f2b57d1ba97e1a3b2280a634):

Since there are 20 ticks in total, I experimented with rotating using the logic `i>10`:

```
var axisGroup = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(0, 1.00, 0.05))
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
    if (i<11) {
      return "rotate(" + (-90 + (d * 360)) + ")";
    }
    if (i>10) {
      return "rotate(" + (90 + (d * 360)) + ")";
    }
  });
```

But that moved the text and the ticks themselves.

Also tried:

```
axisGroup.append("text")
  .attr("x", 275 + 8)
  .attr('y',4)
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + 0 + ")";})
  .text(function(d) {return Math.round(d*100)/100; });
```

But that did not work either, just moved the the text around the circle.

### Question

What call do I need to use to modify the text's rotation (in place), so that it orients right side up and more readable on the left-hand side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to rotate texts inside groups that were already rotated. Because of that, you need to set the center point for the texts (here using your magic numbers):

```
.attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return d > 0.5 ? "rotate(180, 283, 4)" : null;
})
```

Besides that, I'm changing the `text-anchor` of the texts as well:

```
.attr("text-anchor", function(d){ 
    return d > 0.5 ? "end" : "start"
})
```

Here is the forked bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/raw/1cafc4d6d1b498454dfe73572d7a946d/460a937b3ab61a12175d1878e72aa0feaa5ea2e7/